# Getting Static integer from Service

Tags: android

I have activity and service, I would like to get a reference to Service integer, that is being updated from time to time in Service. My problem is that in my Activity I only get that integer first declared Value (for instance 0).

My main goal is to know Services' updated value every time I start my program.

Main activity:

```
if(Service.doesCounter>0){
                        //do something
                //in this state Service.doesCounter always is 0(checked by log)
        }
```

Service:

```
public static int doesCounter=0; // declared after class as class memeber
//code where I start my method does();

.....
public void does(){
        doesCounter++;
        Log.e("cccccc","Service Counter "+doesCounter); // everything ok, value is changing as suppose to.
}
```

**Edit**

my Shared Preferences class:

```
public class AppPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS_preferences"; //  Name of the file -.xml
         private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
         private Editor prefsEditor;

         public AppPreferences(Context context)
         {
             this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
             this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
         }

         public boolean getAnything() {
             return appSharedPrefs.getBoolean("Anything", false);

         }

         public void setAnything(Boolean text) {
             prefsEditor.putBoolean("Anything", text);
             prefsEditor.commit();
         }
```

Then from Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected AppPreferences appPrefs;
appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
appPrefs.setAnything(fasle);
```

Then from Service:

```
appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

And when this happens all earlier made changes are reseted, how to make service and MainActivity use same prefs? Maybe I can somehow make AppPrefs class static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using static class fields is considered a bad practice in android. 
Your app's resources may be revoked by the os and another process of your app may be re-initialized whenever the user gets back to it. In this case you will loose doesCounter updates. I don't know if this is the case (it should work in a common scenario where your app is foregrounded, **unless you are running your service in another process** (using the flag [isolatedProcess](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#isolated)) .

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do "the android way" is to store the doesCounter in SharedPreferences.

One way to achieve that is having a static class like this:

```
public class PrefUtils {
private final static String NUM_DOES = "NumDoes";

public static int getNumDoes(Context c)
{
    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, mode);        
    return mySharedPreferences.getInt(NUM_DOES, 0);
}


public static void setNumDoes(int numDoes , Context c)
{
    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, mode);        
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();   
    editor.putInt(NUM_DOES, numDoes);
    editor.commit();

}
```

And you are done. Just call PrefUtils.getNumDoes / setNumDoes

Comment: 1.Yes, my service has a separate process because without separating I did not managed to make it not be killed when my app is closed(when user press back in my application my application and service a both killed(Service has return sticky))
2. Yes I was using shared prefs before but I had a problem because I am using shared prefs also in my Activity, so I did not managed to use same shared prefs for both activity and service(I used separate class for shared prefs and by creating object of it in both service and mainActivity it somehow reseted already inserted values)

Comment: Well, I guess you need to figure out to make shared prefs working (it's pretty simple, though) because given that you have the service in a different process, they have a different memory space and the activity is not able to access the other service's memory).

Comment: Maybe you can help me? Please look at my Edited post.